# Can MSTest run a specific method each time it startsup?

Tags: mstest

**Question**

Is there a way to have a method that will *always* run anytime that test assembly is run through MSTest?

Similar to how the [TestInitialize] and [ClassInitialize] attributes work, but for the entire assembly.  I do not want to have to add code to every test class's [ClassInitialize] method.

**Reasoning**

Some of my tests interact with the database.  They delete data and other things that would be very harmful to a production database.  There is only a configuration file that tells my unit test project to run against the non-production database.

I would feel better if there was a method that would run on startup that would say "Okay Database name is not 'production'"

**Ideas**

Log4Net uses an assembly attribute to configure itself.

```
using log4net.Config;
[assembly: XmlConfigurator()]
```

Perhaps I can do something simliar?

```
[assembly:  CheckDatabaseNameNot("production")]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried [AssemblyInitialize]?

Comment: I thought I looked for such an attribute, but alas yes that does work.  I can throw an exception from the method if the database saftey check fails.

Comment: I thought you were joking at first when I read your answer -- because I was so sure I looked for it before asking my question!

Comment: Lol, yeah we've all been there before.